# how to get duplicate entry from database mysql with id duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

i want back ids duplicate from mysql
this is my query

```
>     SELECT COUNT(title) AS duplicate_Count , title , id
>     FROM lyric
>     GROUP BY title
>     HAVING COUNT(title) > 1
```

and result is this:

```
duplicate_Count  title id
2     text     121
3     text_2    233
```

But I'd like this result:

```
duplicate_Count  title id
2     text     121 , 122
3     text_2    233 ,260 ,56
```

any help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL group certain results into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060332/mysql-group-certain-results-into-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `id` to `GROUP_CONCAT(id)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(title) AS duplicate_Count , title , GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM lyric
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(title) > 1
```

[Example](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)